# When is necessary to create a new app (with startapp) in Django?

Tags: python, django

Ive found this question, but the answer was from 2008, and I couldnt find any current answer, so I wanted to know if there is a good place to find current information about it, or if you have any advice about it I would be very grateful.

Comment: whenever you think two things are different

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `./manage.py startapp` when you already started a project. Code is developed inside apps.

You may use 2nd `./manage.py startapp` if you wan't to split functionality in your project maybe to be reused in some other app. Example of such an app is administration, django-rest-framework and others.

If you are just doing a small project you will be fine with one app per project.